# Origin of the word "cum"

Tags: etymology

What is the origin of the word *cum*?  I'm trying to find the roots for its prevalent usage, especially in North America.

Comment: Yes, I am referring to sperm.

Comment: Such nonsense! It means "together with" and is actually a Latin preposition with the same meaning as in English. Oh you mean...

Comment: I thought it was short for "come to climax", but that's just a guess.

Comment: When used as a noun, it usually refers to sperm. When used as a verb, it can be used to describe both men and women. You didn't mention part of speech, although @Kevin made that helpful distinction in his answer, i.e. between noun and verb.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's an informal way of spelling **'to come'**, which can mean *having an orgasm*. 
How exactly that verb has become associated with sexual acts is unclear (to me). My best guess would be that it was commonly used in a phrase similar to:

> I'm coming to an orgasm!

Comment: Was the first example specifically meant to testify of single-m usage?

Comment: "The vicar's late coming!", said Mrs Brown, stirring her tea with the other hand. :)

Answer (score 36):

Etymonline [explains](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=cum):

> *cum* (verb and noun) seems to be a modern (by 1973) variant of the sexual sense of *come* that originated in pornographic writing, perhaps first in the noun sense. This "experience sexual orgasm" slang meaning of *come* (perhaps originally *come off*) is attested from 1650, in "Walking In A Meadowe Greene," in a folio of "loose songs" collected by Bishop Percy. [...]
>
> As a noun meaning "semen or other product of orgasm" it is on record from the 1920s. The sexual *cum* seems to have no connection with Latin *cum*, the preposition meaning "with, together with," [...].

To this, I will add that as far as the verb *come* is concerned, there are similar constructions in German (*kommen*) and French (*arriver*).

Comment: and also Italian (venire)

Comment: Dutch (klaar)komen.

Comment: P.S. Only used as a verb. Komen = to come in normal language. Funnily, it is not considered vulgar at all, as far as sexual terms go: it is rather neutral, because it is non-graphic.

Comment: In Japanese it is *iku* (to go).

Comment: This tells us **when** this spelling appeared, but not **why** (which would be a part of a full account of its 'roots', that the question was about). In particular, it would be interesting to know whether the people who started the practice in the seventies consciously created the spelling in order to more clearly separate the sex-related sense of the word from its primary sense, or the practice emerged from somebody's having mistakenly though that these are entirely different words which had already had different spellings.

Answer (score 9):

The Oxford English Dictionary has a definition for "Come" that first developed in 1440 that may have the answer for the double entendre that is "Cum."

When roasting certain grains during the malting process, the malt rises at the top and sometimes shoots off. This was referred to as the "come." Like in this example, "In Corn, [the Radicle] is that Part, which Malsters, upon its shooting forth, call the Come."

Comment: Gee, who would ever have connected sexual activity with alcohol manufacturing? ;)

Answer (score 1):

According to [Etymonline.com](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=cum&searchmode=none), the noun *cum* has had its current sexual connotation since the 1920s. As a verb, it goes back much farther.

Answer (score -1):

I think it is how people with poor written English language skills believed the verb "to come" (to orgasm) was spelled. The misspelling results from confusion with a shortened form of the word "scum" (as in "scumbag") referring to male ejaculate.

Comment: I have never heard 'scum' used to describe male ejaculate.  Scum is what you scrape from the bottom of your work boots, or extract from a clogged sink drain.

Comment: @oosterwal: http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=scumbag&searchmode=none

Comment: @Anguish: [I see your reference and raise you another.](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=scum)

Comment: @oosterwal: Acknowledged. 'Scum' did come* to mean ejaculate in some contexts, but not, apparently, in a timeframe that would have influenced this spelling. [* No pun intended. Really.]