# How does one use the Latin word "cum" in a sentence?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, latin

I'm talking about the Latin *cum*, which I've seen used conjunctively, as in *A-cum-B*.  What does it mean, and how do you use it?

Comment: Needless to say that these times `cum` is usually used as slang for sperm, so I wouldn't use it with your meaning to avoid unwanted comedy effects. For example I would probably laugh if you were to say `bedroom-cum-study`..

Comment: Related: [Origin of the word “cum”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7949/origin-of-the-word-cum).

Answer (score 30, accepted):

*Cum* is the Latin word for *with* and is usually used to join two nouns, showing that something serves two purposes.

*She is a waitress-cum-singer in the restaurant.*

*This is my bedroom-cum-study.*

Comment: I would say that part of its use or meaning is that the two nouns / two purposes are not equal though.

Comment: @Hippie - where did you see that? It can happen but it does not strike me as a rule.

Comment: I haven't seen it I've just always taken it that way. A songstress that hasn't made it might work as a waitress but not the other way round hence the comparative rarity of "singer-cum-waitress". And while one who dwells in a residence equipped with a study could sleep there it seems he would have more choice in the matter than one who must use his bedroom as his study.

Comment: I think the word gains currency from homophony with **[be]come**, suggesting duality/equivalence of the surrounding terms. Google returns plenty of results to show that many people actually *write* it as **come**.

Comment: @hippietrail: It doesn't mean the two  nouns / purposes are 'equal' in other more normal contexts. It means the subject or context of the utterance is *forcing* them to be equated, often in contravention of normal logic.

Comment: I'm afraid that, like "intercourse," this is another once-useful word now consigned to the dustbin (at least with respect to polite expression).

Comment: I like the subtle double-entendre in the second example.

Comment: @dbkk: If that's what you call subtle, I wonder what your basement-cum-sweatshop must look like...

Comment: @Jasper Loy: No double-entendre was registered here! If this carries on, *@Peter o' the Corn* will have to change his handle on EL&U. And what about the millions of people with surnames like Balls, or forenames like Fanny? I don't mind a joke, but we're not all 12-year-olds, fer crissakes!

Comment: Cum is not derived from the Latin word for 'with', it is a Latin word for with.

Comment: Much of all this eighth-gradery can be avoided by pronouncing it with a proper Latin pronunciation - COOM, not CUMM.

Comment: @ChrisB.Behrens That is one reason it still works well in graduation speeches.

Answer (score 4):

The word `cum` is Latin for 'with', as in *cum laude*, which means "with honour". It is used in Latin Honors, as in

> **magna cum laude** -- with great honour.
>   or
>   **summa cum laude** --  with highest honour.

As Jasper said, it is used in English to connect to things that are closely related.

Answer (score 3):

About that matter, *[Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=cum)* says of the use of the Latin *cum* preposition:

> The sexual *cum* seems to have no connection with Latin *cum*, the preposition meaning “with, together with”, which is occasionally used in English in local names of combined parishes or benifices (e.g. [Chorlton-cum-Hardy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chorlton-cum-Hardy)), in popular Latin phrases (e.g. *cum laude*), or as a combining word to indicate a dual nature or function (e.g. slumber party-cum-bloodbath).

It's to be noted that both have the same pronunciation (/kʌm/ in British English, /kəm/ in American English). Both *Etymonline*, the *New Oxford American Dictionary* and *Cambridge Advanced Learner’s Dictionary* have it written “X-cum-Y”, with hyphens. Funnily, the later two use related examples, *NOAD* going for “study-cum-bedroom” and *Cambridge* for “bedroom-cum-study”.

However, modern usage doesn't always follow that prescription, at least in American English. The [*Corpus of Contemporary American English*](http://www.americancorpus.org/) data for 2010 shows 11 occurrences using hyphens, and 3 occurrences without hyphens (such as “lawyer cum fitness enthusiast”, [right there](http://www.menshealth.intoday.in/menshealth/storyprint.jsp?contentid=3221&sid=5&cid=22)).

Comment: I must lead a sheltered life. Google's millions of hits for *study-cum-bedroom* only make me think of the tiny 'box-bedroom' in a lot of so-called 3-bedroom houses. So far as I'm concerned, the sexual use is just a deliberately abberant spelling of *come [to a climax]*.

Answer (score 0):

It also means "when" when it is presence of a subjunctive e.g. cum portavisset - "When he had carried"